# Can Javascript tell JavaFX to spawn a thread and be notified when complete?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to see if I can do the following:

- Have some Javascript make a call to JavaFX.
- Have JavaFX then spawn a thread to do work it has been given from the Javascript.
- Come back to the Javascript and allow it to continue while JavaFX is working with the spawned thread.
- Then have JavaFX notify the Javascript when the work from the spawned thread is done.

From my understanding, there is no real widely supported multithreading for Javascript. I'm working on a project with Javascript and JavaFX though and it would help if this worked instead. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT** 
I'm using the WebEngine in JavaFX to handle a UI and using HTML with Javascript to create the UI. I am not using [Nashorn jjs -fx](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/jjs_fx).

Comment: Please edit your auestion to describe how you are using JavaScript with JavaFX?  Are you using [Nashorn `jjs -fx`](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/jjs_fx)?

Comment: Is it possible to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) (just absolutely minimal executable sample code) of what you have tried so far in your question? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have anything so far because I have not idea how to do so or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something like this last week but got an error on the virtual machine every time I tried to do the callback from javascript to javafx.

nevertheless, in the WebEngine Api

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html

There is a little example about how to do this in a section called "Calling back to Java from JavaScript".

If the example works for you you would only need to start a task after that and there is an article about concurrency in javafx that talks about it

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

The little program I made checks for a javascript object using the executeScript() function everytime the loadWorker changes and if the object exists it executes a task.

I think although i did not checked this that If the example fails to work maybe you could try using the confirmHandler or the promptHandler included in the WebEngine to start your tasks.